# Applescript to shell script watch folder

Tags: shell, shell-script, applescript

I am trying to setup a watch folder so that when a file is added to a folder, I can run a shell script...for this purpose I made a simple test but cannot make it work...

Here is my applescript

```
on adding folder items to theWatchedFolder after receiving theDetectedItems
    activate
    display dialog "Transcode Successful"
    do shell script "/Users/wme/Desktop/script.sh" & theDetectedItems
end adding folder items to
```

and the script.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
f="$1"
do
    name=$(basename "$f")
    dir=$(dirname "$f")
    notify-send "$name"
done
```

While it does alert me "Transcode Successful" So I do know that the applescript is working...I dont get notified via the shellscript that the correct filename has transmitted...how do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

```
on adding folder items to p after receiving input
    set l to {}
    repeat with f in input
        set end of l to quoted form of POSIX path of f
    end repeat
    set text item delimiters to " "
    do shell script "bash ~/Desktop/script.sh " & (l as text)
end adding folder items to
```

You can also use Automator to create folder actions that run shell scripts directly:

[image]

Comment: using `l` as a variable is very confusing because it looks like the number `1`. I spent ages trying to work out how your script worked until I realised.